# Data export limit in Sql Developer for excel file

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, export-to-excel, dbeaver

I am facing an issue which is quite strange while exporting data into and `.xlsx` file from the SQL Developer result set. I ran the same query on SQL Developer and on Dbeaver. When I export data from SQL Developer to a `.xlsx` file the number of rows exported into the sheet were `47519` and when I exported the same data into a `.xlsx` file via Dbeaver the number of rows was `87936`.

I am now confused either the limit is being exceeded here for SQL Developer or some other issue. Well, I tried another result set and then the number of rows exported by SQL Developer jumped to `49916` and in Dbeaver the rows were around `87534`.

It's causing so much trouble because from the past few weeks I've relied on the data files exported via SQL Developer.

I just want to know what possible issue I could be facing here.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are connecting to the same database with the same user in both tools?

Comment: Do you know exact number of rows to be exported? Did you check it by `select count(*) from (your current query goes here)`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well there's only 1 database so yes. And I have make sure by extracting data for 1 particular item and it is returning data fine it just messes up with large amount of data

Comment: @Littlefoot I haven't checked the count but let me check

Answer (score 6):

I think you're running into a bug with version 19.2 of SQL Developer

Set your output type to CSV, or upgrade to version [19.4](https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqldev-downloads.html) where this is fixed.

Or, remove the DATE columns from your query.

This is the Bug description mentioned in the 19.4 release notes for bug fixes.

"Excel export limited to 32k, null dates truncate output"

Comment: Having the same issue... looking at my version...19.2... shit...
Thx for saving me another houre of debugging...

Answer (score 1):

To handle the xls limit, SQLDeveloper will create one or more new sheets within the file for the additional rows. When you open your worksheet, you should see a tab at the bottom for each sheet created.

.CSV then convert it to Excel

- second solution :

You could try the version 3.1EA2 which is able to write .xlsx

. That one can hold more than 65535 rows.

Answer (score 0):

As @thatjeffsmith explained that the issue consists in **null dates** **causing the truncation**, I tried the following trick as a workaround:

> NVL ( TO_CHAR ( < **MY_DATE** > ) , '**XXX**' )

In this way I **succeeded in exporting to Excel the entire query** result.

By the way, **I didn't have inside my table any null dates from the start**. How come the original result, without the aforementioned workaround, have been truncated, @thatjeffsmith?

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend using SQL Developer for this task - I was bitten by it several times with most simple export actions not working without errors - the export feature of this tool is not something you want to rely on! Also csv exports are broken e.g. when result sets contain numbers with comma as delimiter it is not properly escaped or quoted what leads to invalid data - take care!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This information would be more helpful as a comment to the original question instead of an answer.